# Using `SKNode` as "world container" triggering NSException

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode7

I've been having problems with working with `SKNode`-s as a "container" that has various sprites on it. I want to do it in this manner because I want to be able to just move this whole `SKNode`, instead of moving every component by itself. I would appreciate if anyone could explain what I am doing wrong. Here is an example where I removed everything that does not cause any errors and left just the part that causes an error.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let jumper = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "doodler.png")
    let brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brick.png")
    let worldNode = SKNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        addChild(worldNode)
        setupBricks()
    }

    func addBrick() {
        let randomX = random(min: size.width*0.1, max: size.height*0.9)
        let randomY = random(min: size.width*0.1, max: size.height*0.9)
        brick.position = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY)
        brick.name = "brick"
        brick.size = CGSizeMake(70, 10)
        brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.size)
        worldNode.addChild(brick)
    }

    func setupBricks() {
        for _ in 0...10 {addBrick()}
    }
```

In another game I had a problem that every time two certain objects collided, the game would crash and give me the same error I am having right now:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: But how can you add the node "brick" more than once? The error "the child has already a parent" appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a class o brick:

```
class Brick: SKSpriteNode {

    init(position:CGPoint) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "brick.png")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
        self.position = position
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.size)
    }
```

and in your Scene:

```
func addBrick() {
    let randomX = random(min: size.width*0.1, max: size.height*0.9)
    let randomY = random(min: size.width*0.1, max: size.height*0.9)
    let position = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY)
    let brick = Brick(position)     
    worldNode.addChild(brick)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code simply you call a child, for example a "brick" that is `nil`.

Check your code ad protect it like:

```
if let nodeToAdd: SKSpriteKit = self.childNodeWithName("brick")  {
    addBrick(nodeToAdd)
}
```